# Did all axiomatic systems face a crisis with the discovery of Russell's paradox?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, paradoxes

When Bertrand Russell outlined his paradox to Gottlob Frege just as his *Grundgesetze* was going to print, it effectively destroyed the consistency of Frege's theory of arithmetic.  But was this the case for all axiomatic theories of arithmetic, including Peano's?  Did they all, either implicitly or explicitly, rely on some form of the axiom of unrestricted comprehension?

Comment: How many axiomatic theories of arithmetic were there, back when Russell knocked Frege over?

Comment: Other than Peano, I am not sure.  But I believe his works were a consolidation of systems derived by Dedekind, Pierce and Frege's Begriffsschrift.  And Cantor's set theory?

Comment: So, are you just asking about arithmetic (as in the body of the question)? or are you asking about all axiomatic systems (as in the title of the question)? If the latter, I don't think Euclid's axiomatic theory of plane geometry would have been affected. Did Cantor actually supply a set of purported axioms for set theory?

Comment: Just about arithmetic, perhaps the title of the question could have been worded more precisely.  I believe the predicate logic of Begriffsschrift was unaffected by Russell's paradox, as this preceded his introduction of Basic Law V.

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ (You should also probably add the link you posted as a comment to the deleted answer for context.)

Comment: No, Russel's paradox just forced the mathematicians to make set theory weaker.